# trim Audio File in iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, avmutablecomposition

I am working on an Audio Mixture iPhone App. Now I want to trim the audio file. I am trying to use `removeTimeRange` method from `AVMutableComposition`, but I don't understand how to use it. Please can someone guide me on how to do that?

Comment: Can you include the code you have tried so far? What has gone wrong with it?

Comment: Problem is I am not getting how to pass value from audio file to removeTimeRange method.

Comment: Without any code nobody is going to know how to help you. Have you already created the mutable composition object? Have you already got the time range defined?

Comment: Hey jrturton, For trimming I was done R&D. Then I found that removeTimeRange method from AVMutableComposition can be use for trim Audio. Then I was read about it. But I am not getting how to get return from this function. So if you know about it then please help me. Thank you.